# Does "F(x) is isometric" imply "F(x) is linear"?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm asked to prove that if $F(x)$ is isometric and satisfies $F(0) = 0$ then $F(x)$ must be linear.

I've got a pretty rigorous proof that "$F(x)$ is isometric" $\implies$ "$F(x)$ is linear" and thus the condition $F(0) = 0$ need not be satisfied. (My "proof" however assumes that angles don't change under a isometric transformation, but this seems reasonable).

**My Question:** Why is the condition $F(0) = 0$ needed? I realize that if that condition is satisfied, then $F(x)$ is simply a rotation in 2D. But I can't find any isometric transformation where $F(0) \neq 0 $ which isn't linear.

Comment: Isometric on what kind of space?

Comment: @Astyx Yeah I was thinking exactly that, but the way the assignment is formulated leaves me in doubt.

Comment: @anomaly $R^n --> R^n$. It's undergraduate, no fancy spaces

Comment: Isometric may be used here to indicate that the metric $d(v, w) = \|v - w\|$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is preserved, in which case the $F(0) = 0$ condition is necessary.

Comment: @Astyx For example, try F(x)=x+v. Does it preserve d(x,y)? But F(0)?

Comment: @anomaly Thank you! I think it makes somewhat more sense now. I just naturally assumed isometry meant $|v| = |F(v)|$ but in the assignment it is defined as $|F(v) - F(w)| = |v - w|$. And $F(0) = 0$ makes my assumption true: $|F(v) - F(0) = |v-0|| \implies |F(v)| = |v|$.

Am I understanding everything correctly?

Comment: Looks like it, yeah.

Comment: Let me also remark that $\|v\| = \|F(v)\|$ for all $v \in \Bbb{R}^n$ alone is not enough to produce linearity.

Comment: @SangchulLee Are you 100% sure? Cause I am pretty sure I've got a proof. What in addition to ||v|| = ||F(v)|| is needed?

Comment: If you assume in addition that $F$ preserves angle, the $F$ becomes linear.

Comment: @SangchulLee That it preserves the angle is implied by it being a isometric transformation, atleast to my (granted, limited) understanding)

Comment: Yes. I was simply saying that the condition $\|F(z)\| = \|z\|$ itself is not enough to characterize isometry.

Comment: @SangchulLee Aah I see :) Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the standard Euclidean vector space $\mathbb{R}^1$ and let $F : \mathbb{R}^1 \to \mathbb{R}^1$ be the non-linear map defined as $F(x) = x + 1$. Even though $F(0) = 1 \neq 0$, this map is an isometry, because we have
$$
\lvert F(x) - F(y) \rvert
= \lvert (x+1) - (y+1) \rvert
= \lvert x - y \rvert \;.
$$

Answer (score 0):

> (My "proof" however assumes that angles don't change under a isometric transformation, but this seems reasonable).

This is correct. Being an isometry is a very strong condition. If $F$ is an isometry, then $F$ also preserves angles. For an example in 2D, we can see that $F$ sends $\Delta ABC$ to a congruent triangle $\Delta A'B'C'$:
[image]

In the picture, the mapping $F$ is a reflection across the line $DE$.